# Error trying to call Java method from Rascal

Tags: rascal

I am trying to call a Java method from Rascal, but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot link method com.mypackage.Teste because: class not found
```

Rascal code:

```
@javaClass{com.mypackage.Teste}
java void testeJava();
```

Java code:

```
package com.mypackage;

public class Teste {
    public void testeJava() {
        System.out.println("it worked");
    }
}
```

The `com.mypackage` package is inside my `src` folder, along with all of the Rascal code. I've also tried to use `src.com.mypackage.Teste` as well, but had the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you know if Rascal will import Java source code or byte code, I mean Java compiled classes?

Comment: Rascal will bind with compiled Java classes, the interface is based on some undocumented patterns. Reading some source code of the rascal library will show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class needs one constructor that has one argument of the `IValueFactory` type. You will often store this in a field, as it is the way to respond to the function call. (Build IValues with this factory)

```
package com.mypackage;

import io.usethesource.vallang.IValueFactory;

public class Teste {
    private final IValueFactory vf;

    public Tests(IValueFactor vf) {
       this.vf = vf;
    }
    public void testeJava() {
        System.out.println("it worked");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting another error: `Cannot link method com.mypackage.Teste because: com.mypackage.Teste.<init>(org.rascalmpl.value.IValueFactory)`. I'm importing `IValueFactory` from `org.rascalmpl.value.IValueFactory`, which is a different package from your example. Could that be the issue?

Comment: hi! that class `org.rascalmpl.value.IValueFactory‌​` I don't know about; that seems wrong. Where does it come from? Perhaps this is from an old stable released plugin? I'd recommend updating to a later version.