# IValueFactory error trying to call Java method from Rascal

Tags: rascal

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855421/error-trying-to-call-java-method-from-rascal). I am trying to call a Java method from Rascal, but I'm getting an error (this time a different one):

`Cannot link method com.mypackage.Teste because: com.mypackage.Teste.<init>(io.usethesource.vallang.IValueFactory)`.

Rascal code:

```
@javaClass{com.mypackage.Teste}
java void testeJava();
```

Java code:

```
package com.mypackage;

import io.usethesource.vallang.IValueFactory;

public class Teste {
    private final IValueFactory vf;

    public Teste(IValueFactory vf) {
       this.vf = vf;
    }
    public void testeJava() {
        System.out.println("it worked");
    }
}
```

I noticed that I was using an old Rascal version (0.8), as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855421/error-trying-to-call-java-method-from-rascal#comment82825005_47858685) comment. I changed it to 0.9 but the error remains. I'm using Eclipse Rascal plugin.

Comment: This code should work (at least it works in Rascal 0.9.1). There may be something strange with your Rascal and/or Java setup. Do you have a bin folder with a Teste.class in it? You you have any strange projects in your Eclipse (such as an (incompatible) version of the vallang sources)?

Comment: (Also, note that once you get it to work, you probably won't see the result of the println and/or you'll find it in the terminal you started Eclipse from). Alternatively, you could have it return a string: public IString testeJava() {
        return vf.string("it worked");
    }

Comment: Yes, I do have a bin folder with Teste.class in it. I'm trying to find any inconsistencies in the setup. I followed http://www.rascal-mpl.org/start/ to get Rascal up and running.

Comment: Did you restart the Rascal console after fixing the constructor? It may not have loaded the new version of your class

Comment: Yes, I also reinstalled RCP Eclipse and everything, but it's still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162093/discussion-between-urielsilva-and-anya).

Answer (score 4):

So, to summarise the discussion, likely causes of this error include:

1. Your Java class needs a public constructor that takes an IValueFactory argument, as seen in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47855421/error-trying-to-call-java-method-from-rascal?noredirect=1&lq=1). E.g.,`public ClassName(IValueFactory vf) { this.vf = vf; }`
2. You have added (1), and the Java class has been recompiled, but Rascal didn't reload it – in which case the solution is (for now) to close the Rascal console and re-open it. I'm not sure if Rascal intends to check for class file changes.
3. You have (1) and Rascal does reload the class, but the class file hasn't been recompiled, which seems to have been the problem in this case.
4. As [jurgenv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1768565/jurgenv) mentions, your Eclipse project also needs both the Rascal and Java natures, otherwise the Java builder doesn't run. This should be correctly set up from the start, as long as you created it using *New → Rascal Project*. For reference, the natures part of your Eclipse .project file should look like this:

   ```
   <natures>
     <nature>rascal_eclipse.rascal_nature</nature>
     <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
     <nature>org.eclipse.pde.PluginNature</nature>
     <nature>rascal_eclipse.term_nature</nature>
   </natures>
   ```

Comment: Perhaps the code is not located in an Eclipse project with the Rascal and Java natures enabled? In this case I'd create a new Rascal project using the wizard and copy the code there.